# How to set the value of a calculated field when creating an item via the PODIO API

Tags: api, calculated-field, podio

I want podio to perform the calculation on a calculated field when I create an item with API

I'm using the PODIO API to create an item from an app. One of the fields of the item is a calculated field, the concatenation of 3 other fields.

If I set only these three fields, the item is created, but the calculated field in the newly created item stays empty.
But if I perform the concatenation and try to set the calculated field myself at item creation, podio returns an error "Values cannot be set directly for field with id XXX", and the item is not created at all.

I'm using node to perform the request, without any podio sdk. The API calls are ok, as I can create the item when I don't try to set the calculated field in the post request.

```
// field id 178064352 is the calculated one
let attributes = {
  '178064352' : [receipt.type + ' / ' + receipt.date + ' / ' + receipt.total],
  '178064354' : [receipt.date], 
  '178064355' : [receipt.type],
  '178064356' : [receipt.total]
}
this.http.post(`${this.PODIO_API_URL}/item/app/${appId}/?silent=true`, {fields:attributes});
```

How can I make podio perform the calculation ? Or force the filling of the value with my own calculated value ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, last time I tried It worked : the calculated field **hasn't to be present at all** in the attributes. Podio calculates it when it receives the others fields.

```
let attributes = {
  // '178064352' : [receipt.type + ' / ' + receipt.date + ' / ' + receipt.total],
  '178064354' : [receipt.date], 
  '178064355' : [receipt.type],
  '178064356' : [receipt.total]
}
this.http.post(`${this.PODIO_API_URL}/item/app/${appId}/?silent=true`, {fields:attributes});
```